# Laravel. Policy for show index

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to display a form for a user who has an 'admin' role. How i can do it? Now i get, always false.

**Policy**

```
public function view(User $user)
{
    foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
        $role->name == 'admin';
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if($user->can('view', $user))
    {
        $listSections = Section::all();
        return view('sections.index', compact('listSections'));
    }
    else
    {
        abort(403, 'Only admins can');
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@can('view')
     @include('sections.show')
@endcan
```

Thx for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are in the situation where your are trying to authorize an action that does not require any model. Let me explain.

From the Laravel documentation:

> The User model that is included with your Laravel application includes two helpful methods for authorizing actions: can and cant

That means Laravel will pass an instance of the user model as the first argument of every "can" action method (`view()` in your case). So when you declare the action method (`view()` in your case), the first argument should always be `User $user`. Which you did.

However when you write `$user->can('view', $user)`, the first `$user` variable - the one on the left of the object operator (the arrow) - references the first argument of the `view()` method. And the second `$user` variable - the second argument of the `can()` method - should be the second argument of your `view()` method. Here is the problem. You should have:

```php
public function view(User $authenticatedUser, User $user)
{
    foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
        $role->name == 'admin';
    }

    return true;
}
```

But this is totally useless in your case.

Actually your `view()` method does not need any model. In this case you can simply specify the class name that needs to be used to determine which policy to use when authorizing the action. You can do:

```php
if ($user->can('view', Section::class)) {
    $listSections = Section::all();
    return view('sections.index', compact('listSections'));
}
```

I suggest you read these paragraphs of the Laravel documentation:

- [Policy Methods Without Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#methods-without-models)
- *Actions That Don't Require Models* paragraphs in [Authorizing Actions Using Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies)

By the way:

Your `view()` method will always return `true`. The `foreach` is kind of useless. Maybe try to use Laravel collections like this:

```
public function view(User $user)
{
    $isUserAdmin = user->roles->search(function($role) {
        return $role->name === 'admin';
    });

    return ($isUserAdmin !== false) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: I used your advice and its work, but method `can()`, It stopped working, because `is undefined` :O. Now i used `$this->authorize('view', Section::class);` 
Its good?
Thank you very much for the exhaustive answer and help ;)

Comment: Are you sure that the user exists? Otherwise the `$user` variable would be null and the `can()` method would be undefined. Using the `authorize()` helper is good, it is even what the doc recommends when working in the controller ;)

Comment: ohh, i find guilty. `$this->authorize('index', Section::class);` I forgot comment before method `can()`.

Now all works. Again thx for your help.

Comment: Glad I helped ;)

Comment: why don't use Gates?

Answer (score -1):

Have u registered the policy in `AuthServiceProvider`?

Comment: yes, `protected $policies = [
        'App\Section' => 'App\Policies\SectionPolicy',
    ];`